# What is the responsibility of a co-signer upon death of a tenant within the first lease cycle?

Tags: contract-law

During the first lease cycle of a rental agreement, the tenant died.  Is the co-signer responsible for damages to the apartment, or do the charges revert to the deceased tenant's family members?

Comment: Any claims would probably go against the tenants estate first, then recovery against the cosigner after that. What state/country is this situation in? What are the amounts of the damages?

Comment: Minnesota (US).  Damages nearly $10k.

Comment: There aren't assets, and thus no probate